# In Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, how to upload a csv file generated in a notebook directly into a bucket?

Tags: python, save, cloud, bucket, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In my notebook, I generated a .csv file from a dataframe, and now I want to upload it into my bucket. How can I do that?
So far, I've only been able to generate the .csv, it appears in the file list in the left corner of the screen; I have to click to download it, open my bucket in OCI and upload the file manually. I want the notebook the upload it directly into the bucket. If there is a code to read files from the bucket, I think it's probably possible to upload it to the bucket aswell.

**I tried to run this code provided by Oracle team:**

```
# coding: utf-8
# Copyright (c) 2016, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
# This software is dual-licensed to you under the Universal Permissive License (UPL) 1.0 as shown at https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/upl or Apache License 2.0 as shown at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. You may choose either license.

# Uploads all files from a local directory to an object storage bucket
# using multiple processes so that the uploads are done in parallel.
#
# Assumptions: Object storage bucket already exists. See object_crud.py for
#                an example of creating a bucket.
#              Loads configuration from default profile in the default config
#                file

import oci
import os
import argparse
from multiprocessing import Process
from glob import glob


def upload_to_object_storage(config, namespace, bucket, path):
    """
    upload_to_object_storage will upload a file to an object storage bucket.
    This function is intended to be run as a separate process.  The client is
    created with each invocation so that the separate processes do
    not have a reference to the same client.

    :param config: a configuration dictionary used to create ObjectStorageClient
    :param namespace: Namespace where the bucket resides
    :param bucket: Name of the bucket in which the object will be stored
    :param path: path to file to upload to object storage
    :rtype: None
    """
    with open(path, "rb") as in_file:
        name = os.path.basename(path)
        ostorage = oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient(config)
        ostorage.put_object(namespace,
                            bucket,
                            name,
                            in_file)
        print("Finished uploading {}".format(name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = oci.config.from_file()
    object_storage = oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient(config)
    namespace = object_storage.get_namespace().data

    description = "\n".join(["This is an example to show how multiple files can be uploaded to in",
                             "parallel. The example uses multiple processes.",
                             "",
                             "All the files in 'directory' will be uploaded to the object storage bucket",
                             "specified by 'bucket_name'  The default profile is used.",
                             "",
                             "The bucket must already exist. See object_crud.py for a bucket creation",
                             "example."])

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description,
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(dest='bucket_name',
                        help="Name of object storage bucket")
    parser.add_argument(dest='directory',
                        help="Path to local directory containing files to upload. Do not include trailing path delimiter.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    bucket_name = args.bucket_name
    directory = args.directory
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        parser.usage()
    else:
        dir = directory + os.path.sep + "*"

    proc_list = []
    for file_path in glob(dir):
        print("Starting upload for {}".format(file_path))
        p = Process(target=upload_to_object_storage, args=(config,
                                                           namespace,
                                                           args.bucket_name,
                                                           file_path))
        p.start()
        proc_list.append(p)

    for job in proc_list:
        job.join()
```

**But I got this:**
ConfigFileNotFound: Could not find config file at /home/datascience/.oci/config, please follow the instructions in the link to setup the config file https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm

I don't even know what exactly to replace in the code above. The code for reading the file from the bucket is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing at

**config = oci.config.from_file()**

because your local system is missing an OCI config file (~/.oci/config) to do the authentication. Where are you running this script? Please use [this](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm) link to set up oci config file.